# Unable to change cached username during git clone

Tags: git, git-bash

I am trying to clone an Azure Git Repository from Git Bash, but it keeps asking only for the password, but I need to change the username also to authenticate correctly. I have tried removing all the cached user credentials from the Windows Credentials Manager but still no luck. It looks like somewhere else the information is cached. Can someone shed some pointers pls.

**Please refer to the below screenshot for more detail:**

[image: Git Clone Password Promp]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your email for user with `git config user.email` and name with `git config user.name`.

You can find the `.gitconfig` (which stores above infos) files by `git config --list --show-origin`  and remove or edit them.